# How to get longitude and latitude value when clicking specific area on leaflet map and store it in a variable

Tags: r, shiny

I want to build a simple project in shiny, where when i click in specific area on map, i can get longitude and latitude value and store it in variable (both longitude and latitude store in different variabel) so i can use it for another purpose, such as show the value in valueBox or use the long and lat to updating data frame that i build in same page as map. im using this code

```
ui <- leafletOutput("map", width = 800, height = 800),
      valueBoxOutput("simple_box")


server <- function(input, output, session){
   ## Leaflet map output
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(apartment_map) %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>% 
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(price_mean),
                  weight = 1,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "black",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.5,
                  label = paste0("Kecamatan: ", apartment_map$NAME_2),
                  popup = popup.cont) %>% 
      addLegend("bottomright", 
                pal = pal,
                values = ~price_mean,
                title = "Apartment Price Mean",
                labFormat = labelFormat(digits = 2),
                opacity = 1)
  })

  # Preparing variable to store longitude and latitude
  coordinates <- reactiveValues(latitude = NULL, longitude = NULL)
  
  #Get lngitude and latitude
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    click <- input$map_marker_click
    if (!is.null(click)) {
      coordinates$latitude <- click$lat
      coordinates$longitude <- click$lng
    }
  })
  
  #Show the value in siple value box
  output$simple_box <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = coordinates$latitude,
      subtitle = "Longitude value"
    )
  })
}
```

I read many topic that related to my problem but still get no luck. Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `input$map_marker_click` wrong.
There are several "click" variables on a leaflet map :

- `input$map_marker_click` : get click on a marker and get its layerId or group and coordinates
- `input$map_shape_click` : get click on a polygon, rectangle, circle etc ... and get its layerId or group and coordinates
- `input$map_click` : get the coordinates of a click anywhere on the map

Here I think you want to use `map_shape_click` or `map_click`, because you do not have any markers on you leaflet map in this code.

```
observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click <- input$map_click
    if (!is.null(click)) {
      coordinates$latitude <- click$lat
      coordinates$longitude <- click$lng
    }
  })
```